# Azure Pipeline dynamic parameters to template file from YAML pipeline

Tags: templates, variables, dynamic, azure-devops, yaml

I am currently working with Azure Devops Build Pipelines, and am trying to call a template file to do some tasks from my build yaml.

I am facing some difficulties to pass parameters to the template file. Let assume that this is my template file (simplified) which works fine :

```
parameters:
 iterations: []

steps:
- ${{ each i in parameters.iterations }}:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Get key values ${{i}}"
  name: getKeyValues_${{i}}
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $item = "${{i}}"
      Write-Host "item : $($item)"
      $keyVal = $item -split "_"
      Write-Host $keyVal
      Write-Host "key: $($keyVal[0]) | value: $($keyVal[1])"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=key;isOutput=true]$($keyVal[0])"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value;isOutput=true]$($keyVal[1])"
```

So I want my iterations parameter contain something like this :

```
iterations: ["1_60", "2_40"]
```

Inside my Yaml pipeline I have the following code(also simplified) :

### Not working scenario

```
- task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: Calculate iterations for $(copies) copies
   name: calculateIterations
   inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: |
       # Do some stuf here to get the arrow below from int value = 100 
       $iterations = ["1_60, "2_40"]
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=iterations;isOutput=true]$($iterations)"

- template: container-template.yml 
   parameters:
     iterations: $(calculateIterations.iterations)
```

### Working scenario

```
- task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: Calculate iterations for $(copies) copies
   name: calculateIterations
   inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: |
       # Do some stuf here to get the arrow below from int value = 100 
       $iterations = ["1_60, "2_40"]
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=iterations;isOutput=true]$($iterations)"

- template: container-template.yml 
   parameters:
     iterations: ["1_60, "2_40"]
```

As you can see, the problem is that I am unable to use the output variable of my script to pass it as parameter to my template.
When I run the not working scenario I have the following error :
[image]

I have found this [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/701307/use-of-dynamic-variables-in-yaml-pipelines.html), but no solutions yet...

Comment: i think this would be a runtime\compile time dilemma here, I dont think this approach would work

Comment: Looks like you are right, I didn't found anything on the subject....

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this @RomanLushkin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As what 4c74356b41 said, this is the dilemma at present. In another word, the *Not working scenario* you mentioned does not support to achieve until now.

Now, we must let the `template` know the clear text at **compile** time. Because during this compile time, we have difficulty to do 2 or more things in one step at same time, especially contain compiling variable value, passing to corresponding template dynamic arguments and etc.

---

> Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value
>   '$(calculateIterations.iterations)'

More detailed, during compile time (*after you click **Run** but before pipeline start truely*):

**1)** Firstly we map the value that come from YAML pipeline, to make sure the `- ${{ each i in parameters.iterations }}` has clear value to **start**.

**2)** After it is done, then parse exact value on `name: getKeyValues_${{i}}` in script order.

In your scenario, it cannot even satisfy the first step since what you passed is a variable, and we do not has parse value process here. That's why you saw error said `Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(calculateIterations.iterations)'`.

Another expression of this error message is: **we**(*template*) are looking forward to exact value(s) to map our dynamic parameters, but what you give is a **unrecognized** content `$(calculateIterations.iterations)`. Sorry, we cannot start to run.

Comment: Thank you for this complete explanation. I suspected that my problem was linked to something like you have described, but was not sure.

Comment: There's a uservoice feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/dynamically-populate-runtime-parameters/1020402?space=21&q=dynamic+parameters

Comment: Well... I struggled half a day trying to get this to work...  It kind of limit the use of templates.  This is a huge limitation.  Considering where we are with Html generation, other templating framework and stuff, yaml looks like stone age.